# Multiple CMD commands Managed c++ (or c#)

Tags: c#, c++, cmd

Hey im just wondering would this work for running multiple CMD commands? I have not tested this yet.

```
//multiple commands
System::Diagnostics::Process ^process = gcnew System::Diagnostics::Process();
System::Diagnostics::ProcessStartInfo ^startInfo = gcnew System::Diagnostics::ProcessStartInfo();
//startInfo->WindowStyle = System::Diagnostics::ProcessWindowStyle::Hidden;
startInfo->FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo->Arguments = "/C powercfg -attributes SUB_PROCESSOR 12a0ab44-fe28-4fa9-b3bd-4b64f44960a6 -ATTRIB_HIDE";
startInfo->Arguments = "/C powercfg -attributes SUB_PROCESSOR 40fbefc7-2e9d-4d25-a185-0cfd8574bac6 -ATTRIB_HIDE";
process->StartInfo = startInfo;
process->Start();
```

Or does `startInfo` only work with one argument at a time? If so how would I execute multiple commands without making a `.bat` file and executing that.

Comment: Unrelated, but I always wonder how people can drag typos in variable names through multiple lines of code without even noticing ...

Comment: @Joey, very easily, when using IntelliSense. It also doesn't help if English isn't your native language.

Comment: svick: Ah, I forgot IntelliSense; typing most of my code in a text editor nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote does what it appears to do. It first sets `Arguments` to one value and then overwrites that with another value. So the `Start()` executes only the second command.

I would recommend creating a helper function (or method):

```
void RunPowerCfg(System::String ^id)
{
    System::Diagnostics::Process ^process = gcnew System::Diagnostics::Process();
    System::Diagnostics::ProcessStartInfo ^startInfo =
        gcnew System::Diagnostics::ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo->FileName = "cmd.exe";
    startInfo->Arguments = System::String::Format(
        "/C powercfg -attributes SUB_PROCESSOR {0} -ATTRIB_HIDE", id);
    process->StartInfo = startInfo;
    process->Start();
}

void main()
{
    RunPowerCfg("12a0ab44-fe28-4fa9-b3bd-4b64f44960a6");
    RunPowerCfg("40fbefc7-2e9d-4d25-a185-0cfd8574bac6");
}
```

Depending on what you want to do, you might want to call `process->WaitForExit()` after you start it.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work.  This code:

```
stratInfo->Arguments = "/C powercfg -attributes SUB_PROCESSOR 12a0ab44-fe28-4fa9-b3bd-4b64f44960a6 -ATTRIB_HIDE";
stratInfo->Arguments = "/C powercfg -attributes SUB_PROCESSOR 40fbefc7-2e9d-4d25-a185-0cfd8574bac6 -ATTRIB_HIDE";
```

doesn't set two arguments.  It sets the argument string, and then overwrites it.

If you want to run this twice, you'll have to do something like:

```
void RunProc(System::String ^arguments)
{
    System::Diagnostics::Process ^process = gcnew System::Diagnostics::Process();
    System::Diagnostics::ProcessStartInfo ^startInfo = gcnew System::Diagnostics::ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo->FileName = "cmd.exe";
    startInfo->Arguments = arguments;
    process->StartInfo = startInfo;
    process->Start();

}

RunProc("/C powercfg -attributes SUB_PROCESSOR 12a0ab44-fe28-4fa9-b3bd-4b64f44960a6 -ATTRIB_HIDE");
RunProc("/C powercfg -attributes SUB_PROCESSOR 40fbefc7-2e9d-4d25-a185-0cfd8574bac6 -ATTRIB_HIDE");
```

Of course, you'll want to add error handling etc to this, especially for the case where the current process doesn't have the right permissions.

Comment: Ah ok this makes more sense, as for error handling in this case do you mean asking for the user to allow these commands to run? (admin rights?)

Comment: For error handling, I mean wrapping the call to `process->Start()` in a try/catch block and, depending on what happens, informing the user to run the application as an administrator.  You can learn more about running with admin privileges here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412896/giving-application-elevated-uac

Comment: If this answers your question, don't forget to accept it!  =)