# Unable to update my App programmatically in Win8 - mfc

Tags: visual-c++, windows-8, mfc, exe, updates

I am trying to update my App from the `sysMenu`.

And by doing click on `Update App..` in the `SysMenu`, Updates automatically started.

Its working fine with XP and Win 7,
But when I trying to do the same thing in Win 8 then Its not working.
It gives alert message that `"You do not have sufficient rights to run this App"`.
even if I am logged with Administrator user.

Hint: If I manually run that `Updates.exe` with `run as Administrator` then its also working.

I have attached the screen shot. I don't know why this happen with Win 8 only.

[image]

**Edit**
I have also refer these articles.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb756929(v=msdn.10)

http://www.developerfusion.com/code/7987/making-a-net-app-run-on-vista-with-administrator-priviledges/

Comment: UAC is "always on" with Windows 8. You should look at `Updates.exe`'s manifest and see what privilege level it's requesting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666408/how-to-request-administrator-permissions-when-the-program-starts

Comment: I have checked my `Updates.exe`'s manifest, and in that manifest `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />` also mention. But still its not resolved my issue. Any other suggestion ?

Comment: @ta.speot.is - No, it's not. Anyone can change the behavior. It is same as in Windows 7.

Comment: @Ajay It's different: http://www.brianbondy.com/blog/id/140/ You can disable it, but you have to edit the registry and it's a whole lot harder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am definitely sure that there is something wrong with your manifest file. Please embed the manifest with

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false">
```

with your Updates.exe.

Though even you have tried it, please try it one more time.

The error dialog seen in snapshot is look like its from your app. So there may be some check in your app, which is showing this dialog.

Comment: I got the issue, The issue is in my App while checking the user privileges. Thanks @Ronak Patel.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention if this is your app or not. I assume it's your app, which you have build using the given manifest setting.

You can use Process Explorer to check if it is running with Elevated user permissions or not (check when this dialog comes up). It may be some build issue, you are setting this UAC setting for different project/build, and attempting to run different executable.

Other thing might be with specific user rights in Local Security Policy (I don't know which policy may allow/prevent updates). Or may be with the thread security rights, which is attempting to launch updates.

Comment: I am setting this UAC setting for both, for my App as well as for this Updates.exe, that I have checked. I am also logged in with Administrator rights, so... And I have also try the Process Explorer to check for user permission, but I dont know how to check it, So can you more specify..

Comment: Both? You app and Updates.exe are different, I am lost! Run `procexp.exe`, and select 'Integrity Level' Column to see UAC state.

Comment: I have checked the "Integrity Level", and it show me for my App is "High" and for Updates.exe its "Medium". So... now...??

Comment: "High" is administrator, and "Medium" is normal (not Low, like IE in restricted mode). It simply mean that `Updates.exe` is not running in Admin-mode! You still have not mentioned what your app is and what this `Updates.exe` is!

Comment: So, how can I give the Administrator rights to Updates.exe ? In the manifest I have mention the `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`. Is there any other way to make to make "Medium" to "High" ??

Comment: Still unanswered: What is your-app, and what is Updates.exe?  Are they same?

Comment: Nope.. My App is product base App, And its version is updated by the Updates.exe which is higher version of My App. Hope now you ll clear.

Comment: I quit answering to your vagueness! Sorry!