# Get Access to Directory

Tags: c#

i want to write a program, which can copy all txt files on my local Pc to a specific location. This is no problem so far i have the rights to open the directory. Some directorys throw a UnauthorizedException. Is it possible to first get access and then read the files? This is what iam doing so far:

```
public List<FileInfo> SearchFiles(List<string> pattern) 
{
    List<FileInfo> files = new List<FileInfo>();

    foreach (DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
    {
        var dirs = from dir in drive.RootDirectory.EnumerateDirectories()
                   select new
                   {
                       ProgDir = dir,
                   };

        foreach (var di in dirs)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (string muster in pattern)
                {
                    foreach (var fi in di.ProgDir.EnumerateFiles(muster, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            files.Add(fi);
                        }
                        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
            }
        }
    }

    return files;
}
```

The List with strings give the pattern the method is searching for. For Example all txt files and all files with hallo in name or what ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try promoting the rights of the application when it runs.

[How to request administrator permissions when the program starts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666408/how-to-request-administrator-permissions-when-the-program-starts)

Comment: Good Idea but it seems not working. If i want to access the directory "Documents & Settings" for example i still get UnauthorizedAccess Exception