# How do i pass over a folder/s or file/s when using Directory.GetFiles access denied exception?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
List<string> alltypes = new List<string>();
try
{
    alltypes = Directory.GetFiles(textBox3.Text, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
{

}
if (alltypes.Count > 0)
{
    if (comboBox1.Items.Count > 0)
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
    comboBox1.Items.Add("Possible Extensions");
    foreach (string ext in alltypes)
    {
        if (!comboBox1.Items.Contains(Path.GetExtension(ext)))
            comboBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetExtension(ext));
    }    
}
```

When it gets to the `catch` it just stops, it never continues getting the files so the `List alltypes` is empty. For example in this case in `textBox3.Text` the value is `c:\`.

Comment: What about checking for null / nothing (alltypes == null)?

Comment: @AnthonyHorne His catch is defined by `UnauthorihzedAccessException` so I guess his question is basicly about how to avoid not having the rights to access a folder.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the rights needed to access the folder. There are too many options. For example it could be set by an active directory. Output your exception in the catch block an check the details.

But in general it can be broken down to: [How to request administrator permissions when the program starts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666408/how-to-request-administrator-permissions-when-the-program-starts)