# How to run an exe as an admin from C# code?

Tags: c#

When I run `dism /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V-All`command from command prompt, It works fine.

But same I want to do from C# code. It does not work, Process exists with error code 11.

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "dism.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V-All";
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
int exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
```

Basically I want to run the given command from C# code (with UAC) as it works with command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. That is, you as a programmer, don't get to decide whether or not your code runs with administrative rights. However, you can inform the user that your code *requires* administrative rights and then ask to be granted those rights. How to do that is [covered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666408/how-to-request-administrator-permissions-when-the-program-starts).

Comment: this does not solve my problem, still getting error code 11

Answer (score 1):

try this method,

You'll want to modify the manifest that gets embedded in the program. This works on Visual Studio 2008 and higher: Project + Add New Item, select "Application Manifest File". Change the  element to:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Comment: this does not solve my problem, still getting error code 11