# How to request administrator permissions at runtime?

Tags: c#, runtime, admin

I want to ask for administrator permissions at runtime in my application, but I couldn't find anything, despite the googling and searching. I could only find posts [regarding rights *at startup*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666408/how-to-request-administrator-permissions-when-the-program-starts), I found [one](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ba6b59a7-406d-404c-bd67-9d32d0c43981/how-to-request-admin-rights-at-runtime) but, it was valid for .NET Framework, I can't really use dNF, I am using .NET Core 5.

Anyhow, how do I demand it? Maybe call some C functions from Win32 API? My application is Windows only, that's why I mentioned that. (yes, but I still can't port over from .net 5)

Comment: You can't. If you want to get the OS UAC prompt asking the user to use his/her admin mojo when running the program, only the OS can do that for you, and it is done before your code starts.  When a program starts, it gets a token that identifies the user and his/her permissions and privileges.  When UAC is enabled, an admin user has a non-admin token and an admin token.  As a program starts it gets one of those.  Once the program starts, the token cannot change.  If you need to do this, start up another process with a different token.  BTW, what is _"dNF"_?

Comment: If you don't want the manifest flag, you can start a new process with `new ProcessStartInfo{ Verb = "runas", UseShellExecute = true, ... };`

Comment: Oh, that's a bummer . Guess I'll have to start a new process in that case. Oh and, @Flydog57, `dNF` is short for `.NET Framework`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as my research (May 9, 2021) when, there is no possible way to extend the privileges of the current program. Also see @Flydog57's comment:

> You can't. If you want to get the OS UAC prompt asking the user to use his/her admin mojo when running the program, only the OS can do that for you, and it is done before your code starts. When a program starts, it gets a token that identifies the user and his/her permissions and privileges. When UAC is enabled, an admin user has a non-admin token and an admin token. As a program starts it gets one of those. Once the program starts, the token cannot change. If you need to do this, start up another process with a different token.

The only logical solution is to start a new executable/process whole together with elevated privileges. With C#, you can use [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process).

However, this might change (I have no sources, but it's a possibility) in the future.