# Can I set the properties of an exe file via C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, exe

I am using Unity to build my game. I need the application to always run as administrator.

When I build my game, I right click on the exe that is produced and set 'Run this program as an administrator' on in the Compatibility > Settings section of the exe properties.

I can write an editor script (C#) that'll execute after a build has completed. So I was wondering if I could automate this step so that I do not forget to do it every time I build?

Comment: are you talking about doing something like [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-my-net-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7) for Unity-Windows Application?

Comment: Yes. I want the built exe to always launcht he 'run as administrator' dialogue. I can achieve this manually by right clicking on the exe, going to 'Compatibility' tab, and checking  'Run this program as an administrator' in the 'settings' section

Comment: I don't think that you can do this using post processing in Unity. You should contact Unity support to make sure if there is some other way around.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this solves your issue.
But  you could add an "Application Manifest File" and configure:

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

With this configuration the user gets always a UAC promt.

Answer (score 0):

Do not have a ready made solution but i can give you an idea:

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412896/giving-application-elevated-uac), using this way you can check if your application is running as an administrator, if no, it starts another process with administrative privilege and you can later call:

```
Application.Quit();
```

to terminate the current instance.

Other than this you must have to wrap this code under [platform dependent compilation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html).

I know it is not a best solution, but can fix this issue.

Hope it helps!