# How to run command line with admin right in C#

Tags: c#, cmd, admin-rights

I have referenced some other topics and it comes up the following coding, yet it doesn't work. I allow it creates command window and use "/k" argument keeping the window opened so that I can trace its output.

However, I can see the warning from the window that the command needs admin rights to execute. How can I execute it in admin rights?

```
public void ClearArpCache () {
        ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/user:Administrator \" cmd /k arp -d \""); // same as "netsh interface ip delete arpcache"
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        //processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        //processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processStartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.Default;
        processStartInfo.Verb = "runas";

        Process.Start (processStartInfo);
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log ("ARP table cache cleared.");
    }
```

EDITED:

Try changing from "cmd.exe" to "runas.exe"

```
public void ClearArpCache () {
        ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("runas.exe", "/user:Administrator \" cmd /k arp -d \""); // same as "netsh interface ip delete arpcache"
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        //processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        //processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processStartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.Default;

        Process.Start (processStartInfo);
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log ("ARP table cache cleared.");
    }
```

Comment: i *think* you should solve that beforehand by making sure your application has elevated UAC, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412896/giving-application-elevated-uac

Comment: /user:Administrator is not a listed set of params for cmd .. you sure you didnt mean runas?

Comment: Thank you @BugFinder, I added "runas" in StartInfo, but it doesn't help.

Comment: no dont call cmd.exe in the first place... call runas....

Comment: runas as commented do the trick, check here for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133379/elevating-process-privilege-programmatically

Comment: edited the program, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Just clarified why it failed using "runas". In order to use "runas" in `Verb`, `UseShellExecute` must be firstly turned *true*.

When executing following function, it will pop a window asking for admin rights, just click 'Yes' to begin the execution. Though it is beyond the scope, if possible I want to skip the pop-up window as well.

```
public void ClearArpCache () {
        ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/k arp -d"); // same as "netsh interface ip delete arpcache"
        processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        processStartInfo.Verb = "runas";

        Process.Start (processStartInfo);
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log ("ARP table cache cleared.");
    }
```

Comment: If you don't like to get the UAC popup, you have to [disable it](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-user-account-control-uac-the-easy-way-on-windows-vista/).