# Run command prompt as administrator UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I know there's been several questions related to running a command prompt as an admin. I looked at this solution [How to run command line with admin right in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813861/how-to-run-command-line-with-admin-right-in-c-sharp)
But in UWP you can't set UseShellExecute to true. Is there a way to run a command prompt as admin from a UWP?

Comment: That's not possible.

Comment: Your app must run with elevated privileges, that's all...

Comment: @Gusman, How do I do that?

Comment: Tablet programs are severely restricted, and admin rights is one of such things.

Comment: You must modify the manifest and target WIndows 10. [This](https://stefanwick.com/2018/10/01/app-elevation-samples-part-1/) explains how to do it.