# How can I call a method after User Account Control prompt in C#?

Tags: c#

In my C# Code, I'll be doing some task that requires administrative rights.
So what I want to do is that I want to call a method after showing User Account Control prompt to the user.
When a user clicks on continue or yes in the User Account Control prompt then that particular method should execute.
What will I have to do in my code to achieve this?
Please help me.

Comment: Maybe [Giving application elevated UAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412896/giving-application-elevated-uac) helps.

Comment: Use the click event to plug in your code.