# Permission Exception When Access Protected Drive

Tags: c#

I am trying to read and write from drive C: in my program but every time I select the drive it throws the FileIOPermission exception.Please tell me how to make application to access the protected path without exception.Also the solution works fine when debug in Visual Studio.
Here is exception preview.

**Preview**

[image: Screen Shot]

**Code**`

```
 public void Start()
    {


        try
            {

            if ( !Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(Path.Text).Any()==true)
                {


                MessageBox.Show("Directory is Empty");


                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Sorry cannot read directory because {ex.ToString()}");

            Startthread.Abort();


        }
  }
```

Comment: You dont have access to the C:\ drive content. You could try to use administrator account with max priviledges, and try to set the app manifest file to require administrator's right when run.
Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383288/how-can-i-embed-an-application-manifest-into-an-application-using-vs2008

Comment: I published the application as clickonce so run as admin not support by clickonce.

Comment: Please add the manifest file as I said - and set its priviledges to requireAdministrator

Comment: As I told you I have tried add mainfest file but RequireAdmininstrator not support by ClickOnce.

Comment: Ok sorry, got that.