# How can i terminate batch file which is running in background

Tags: windows, c#-4.0, batch-file

I am creating simple windows services that calls my batch file,Now i want to stop or terminate the batch file by stopping it to the services.msc,my services stop but the batch file is still active in the background.how can i terminate the batch file in the background i will stop my services.

Thank you in advance.

```
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Diagnostics;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.ServiceProcess;
 using System.Text; 
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace Myservices
 {
   public partial class Myservices: ServiceBase
   {
    private ProcessStartInfo processListener;
    Process p;
    public Myservices()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
         processListener = new ProcessStartInfo{

            CreateNoWindow = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            Arguments = string.Format("/C \"{0}\"", "C:\\myservices\\servceupdate.bat"),
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            ErrorDialog = false
        };

        p=Process.Start(processListener);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        p.Close();//Here my batch file did not terminate.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a title inside you batch file `servceupdate.bat`, like so:

```
title servceupdate.bat
```

Then in the script that you want to use to kill the process, you can run this cmd:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%a in ('tasklist /v ^| findstr "servceupdate.bat"') do taskkill /f /pid %%a
```

Comment: Hi @Alex,is that code you provide will be put inside my c# OnStop()?

Comment: Not sure, but if you you try to use it without putting it into a batch file, you need to replace the `%%a` to `%a`

Comment: I tried your code above and put it on the stopper.bat then also i set title on servceupdate.bat,but when i run the stopper.bat it immediately close,the servceupdate.bat did not close,I just manually run my servceupdate.bat so that i can see when it is close.

Comment: I tried again and it's working now,but can i ask what is the purpose of tokens=2 ? also what is /v ^  will do ?,Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You want to use Process Jobs to terminate any child processes when the parent service is stopped.

See

- [Job Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161.aspx)
- [Kill child process when parent process is killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342941/kill-child-process-when-parent-process-is-killed)
- [CreateProcess such that child process is killed when parent is killed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259055/createprocess-such-that-child-process-is-killed-when-parent-is-killed)