# Start a subordinate process

Tags: c#, multiprocess

I would like to start a process from my application with Process.Start() and I would like that in case of my app crash or the user close it then the child process is automatically killed.

Is it possible to obtain something like this?

Comment: [This one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342941/kill-child-process-when-parent-process-is-killed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `AppDomain.ProcessExit` event to catch when your process is about to exit and have it kill the other process. I am unsure as to how it works in reaction to an unhandled exception, so you may have to use `AppDomain.UnhandledException` and have it use FailFast to handle any normal exceptions. As part of that handler, you have it kill the other process too.

Answer (score 0):

You could store PID of lauched child process somewhere, then kill process with that PID in application closing event. Though in case of unhandled crash the child process may retain in memory.