# Kill Child Process when Parent NT Service is Killed/Crashed

Tags: c#, c++, .net, winapi, process

I have a Windows NT Service and a Third Party exe which i want to run as a child process of NT Service, such that as soon as my NT service process crashes, this child process is also killed

For this i found the way of doing this using 
[Kill child process when parent process is killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342941/kill-child-process-when-parent-process-is-killed)

I tried to implement it and worked fine using a normal parent process, but when i do the same in my NT Service as the parent SetInformationJobObject method return false and a Exception with Error Code 0

Exception: _COMPlusExceptionCode = -532462766

What is the difference between a Normal process and a NT Service process which is causing this exception ?

i am using Win2k8 R2 Server machine and C#

[EDIT1]
Exception:
GenericParameterAttributes = '(((System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo)(ex._exceptionMethod)).ReflectedType).GenericParameterAttributes' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
 {"Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true."}

EDIT 2:
Because SetLastError was not set to true in the function defination using DLLImport, so last error was wrong
Correct [ErrorCode is 24](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx/css#ERROR_BAD_LENGTH) which say bad lench of the structure, so what should be the correct structure ?

Edit 3: Correct Length Expected in the case of a NT Servce for my 64 bit win2k8R2 server machine seems to be 144 as compared to 112 as defined in the above post

Edit 4: Is this the only way of doing this, what are other options of doing same ?

Comment: The NT Service is probably running under a different user than the child process?  Any permissions issues to check?

Comment: It bombs with an unhandled managed exception, exception code 0xe0434352.  At a minimum you should implement an event handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException and log e.ExceptionObject.ToString() so you know why your code is crashing.

Comment: FYI, 0xE0434352 is the general CLR exception code, that status value is used under the covers during SEH (structured exception handling) when any CLR Exception is thrown.

Comment: Chris -  its failing in the Job constructor itself :(, even if i remove the child process code it is throwing exception
HansPassant: Added Exception Details, will see if i can figure out something from this exception

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in the structure declaration used by me as defined in thread [Kill child process when parent process is killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342941/kill-child-process-when-parent-process-is-killed)

Structure defined in the above thread are valid for 32 bit applications and
My NT Service was a 64 bit application and for which it requires some changes

Changes Made

- First change the DLL Import of SetInformationJobObject to

  ```
  [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  static extern bool SetInformationJobObject(IntPtr hJob, JobObjectInfoType infoType, IntPtr lpJobObjectInfo, uint cbJobObjectInfoLength);
  ```

  As SetLastError Flag was not set it was not giving me right error Code, after getting the right error code only i was able to get that it is expecting a 144 byte length structure
- Then Chnage the JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION and JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION structures to following

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION
    {
        public Int64 PerProcessUserTimeLimit;
        public Int64 PerJobUserTimeLimit;
        public Int32 LimitFlags;
        public UInt64 MinimumWorkingSetSize;
        public UInt64 MaximumWorkingSetSize;
        public Int32 ActiveProcessLimit;
        public Int64 Affinity;
        public Int32 PriorityClass;
        public Int32 SchedulingClass;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION
    {
        public JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION BasicLimitInformation;
        public IO_COUNTERS IoInfo;
        public UInt64 ProcessMemoryLimit;
        public UInt64 JobMemoryLimit;
        public UInt64 PeakProcessMemoryUsed;
        public UInt64 PeakJobMemoryUsed;
    }
```

Basically as per [JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
and [JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684147%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) we should use data type as per application
SIZE_T = UInt64 vs UInt32
DWORD = Int32

After the changes it worked Fine.