# Have to manually end process each time program is finished running

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, process

Not sure if this is the correct exchange site but here goes:

When I build my WinForms debug version program and execute it on other PC after I exit the program its process is still running, so when I run it again it does nothing and I have to restart the device in order to start it again. It's almost like the OS isn't cleaning up on termination because I don't have this problem on my main PC.

Is there anything programmatic I can do to prevent this?

EDIT: I'm using C# within the .NET framework.

Comment: It's a little hard without seeing any code...

Comment: sounds like you have some unmanaged code resource still in memory.

Comment: @PhilMurray I'm not using any unsafe code, care to elaborate?

Comment: Don't you have any foreground thread that keeps your application alive ?

Comment: without seeing some of your code we have no idea. Are you using a Stream of some kind? Calling a C++ library and not disposing of the object. It could be any number of things

Comment: Apologies, I left out the language and platform. This is all in .NET C#, which is why I'm baffled.

Comment: @Lee: Un*managed*, not un*safe*. It could be a file or network resource that's not been cleaned up. It's also possible that you have a non-background thread running that means your app isn't ending when the UI closes. Perhaps post some code or, more likely, I'd suggest you try to debug the program (remote debugger, or get a memory dump) to see what threads/methods are being executed.

Comment: Wouldn't the CLR dispose of these things automatically?

Comment: @Lee, not for unmanaged resources no. Just because its in the framework does not mean its calling fully managed code

Comment: OK I will try closing and disposing all resources on the exit event.

Comment: You don't need to dispose of all the resources. If you could pose some code perhaps we could point you in the right direction

Comment: The program is a client-server instant message program. The only resources I'm using are Tcp objects and sockets. Could this be because sockets aren't closed and disposed properly?

Comment: @Lee what about post some code are you finding hard to understand.  No one can help you without it.

Comment: TCP app huh?  Likely you have either non-blocking calls and a POLLING LOOP (which could be keeping your app from closing properly), or you are using blocking calls in a separate thread which doesn't have IsBackground() set to True.  Which is it?...as the others have stated, without code this is pointless.

Comment: Just show code how you close your application...

Comment: I don't have any code for handling the exit of the application.

Comment: Sounds like the form closes but the application keeps running. Like @Marshall777 said, do you have any threads that you created that are still running? Listening to the TCP port perhaps?

Comment: Yes I have a couple of threads running indefinite loops so I'll check those.

Comment: @Lee try setting the IsBackground property of your thread objects to true (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx )

Answer (score 1):

This is the hard way, but the right way:
[Kill child process when parent process is killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342941/kill-child-process-when-parent-process-is-killed)

The easy way (Might be sufficient); Handle the Application.ApplicationExit event.
[Application.ApplicationExit Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.applicationexit.aspx)