# Kill child process when application process is killed/crashed

Tags: c#, windows, process, system.diagnostics, user32

I'm creating new processes from my application and want these processes to be killed when/if my application is crashed.

So i found this post: [Kill child process when parent process is killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342941/kill-child-process-when-parent-process-is-killed).
I took the first example and copied all the code to a new class under a function `public void Close()`.

Got an error - The name `Win32` does not exist in the current context so I added `Microsoft.Win32` 
and now another error - 
`CloseHandle` is not recognized.

**The type or namespace name 'CloseHandle' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Win32' (are you missing an assembly reference?**)

How can i fix it ?

Comment: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/CloseHandle.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kill child process when parent process is killed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342941/kill-child-process-when-parent-process-is-killed)

Answer (score 3):

a simpler approach- or so i believe

keep track of all the processes u start.

```
ArrayList chilProcess_id = new ArrayList();

    public void process_starter()
    {            
        Process p;
        p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();           
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "YOUR PROCESS PATH";
        if (!p.Start())
             chilProcess_id.Add(p.Id);
    }
```

Now before exiting, kill those processes.

```
public void exitApplication()
    {
        Process p;
        foreach (int p_id in chilProcess_id)
        {
            p = Process.GetProcessById(p_id);
            try
            {
                if(!p.HasExited)
                    p.Kill();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Handle the exception as you wish
            }
        }
    }
```

for ArrayList add namespace

```
using System.Collections;
```

for Process add namespace

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```