# Kill my application when it is not responding using c#

Tags: c#, c++

I have an application "X" which communicates with another application "Y".
I want to have my application X check when there is no more communication with application Y and if so kill itself and Y.
Application X has GUI written in C# which runs C++ code.
Application Y is written in C++.
How can I do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Similiar question that maybe help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342941/kill-child-process-when-parent-process-is-killed

Answer (score 1):

In your C# app you can call Process.Kill() method on 'Y' app and itself if you lost connectivity

```
Process [] proc Process.GetProcessesByName("your_process");
proc[0].Kill();
```

Comment: I think the OP is asking on how to **know when to kill** the child app, not on **how to kill** an app.

Comment: I am asking both. How to do it and how to know when. Thanks Enrich for the first answer. can anyone answer the second part of the question (how to know when?) Please note that application X and Y are not related. None is child of the other...