# Python program with subprocesses terminates subprocesses on CTRL+C but not on sys.exit()

Tags: python, multiprocessing, termination, sigint

I'm writing a test harness for a multi-process UDP server. The test harness runs multiple subprocesses- including several that spawn instances of the UDP server. I'm having trouble both terminating subprocess on exit and exiting the program from within- the only thing that works is CTRL+C from terminal, which kills the subprocess and stops the program nicely.

I have several related problems:

1. The program does not quit if I use `sys.exit()`, either in the signal handler or after I fire the signal. It looks like it hits the exit code, and then hangs.
2. The program does not terminate the subprocesses if I use `p.terminate()` or `os.kill(p, SIGINT`
3. The program does not terminate the subprocesses if I use `os._quit()`

Again, if I just leave the program running and from the terminal type CTRL+C, the program immediately stops, taking all subprocesses with it. What's the best way to do this from within the program?

---

What I try at the end of the program

```
os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)
```

The signal handler

```
# handle ctrl+c and remove open files
def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print 'You pressed Ctrl+C!'
    # remove all files
    try:
        filelist = [ f for f in os.listdir(tmpdir) ]
        for f in filelist: os.remove(tmpdir+'/'+f)
        # remove dir
        os.rmdir(tmpdir)
    except:
        print "unable to remove temporary directory/files:", tmpdir
    print "attempt sys.exit()"
    sys.exit() # This doesn't do anything, program hangs
    # os._exit(0) # This stops program, but doesn't kill subprocesses

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ensuring subprocesses are dead on exiting Python program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320232/ensuring-subprocesses-are-dead-on-exiting-python-program)

Comment: Already tried that. Using the `os.kill` on each extant subprocess doesn't work, so registering a cleanup handler to do the same thing isn't going to help me.