# wait for process to end in windows batch file

Tags: batch-file

I would like to write a windows script that waits until a given process (PID) has ended before executing something. So far I have (PID=1234):

```
:loop
set VAR="tasklist | find /i " 1234 " /c"
if NOT (' %VAR% ')=="0" goto loop
**do something**
```

but already the line

```
set VAR="tasklist | find /i " 1234 " /c"
```

doesn't work, it stores the string instead of the evaluation. Or maybe it's supposed to? In which case the line

```
if NOT (' %VAR% ')=="0" goto loop
```

should evaluate the contents of VAR, but if I type this manually in a console I just get

```
"tasklist | find /i " was unexpected
```

I understand the double quotes in

```
set VAR="tasklist | find /i " 1234 " /c"
```

are problematic but I need a space on each side of the PID (1234 in the example) to ensure that it is not a substring of another process (like 12345) for it to work properly.

Any DOS experts out there?

Comment: Look at the `for /F` command.

Comment: use `tasklist /fi "pid eq 1234"?` to ensure that it is not a substring of another process

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
:loop
tasklist | find " 1234 " >nul
if not errorlevel 1 (
    timeout /t 10 >nul
    goto :loop
)
```

Get the list, search in the content, if found (on not found errorlevel = 1) wait and loop

To get the data into the variable

```
for /f %%a in ('tasklist ^| find /c " 1234 "') do set "var=%%a"
```

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer for being concise and complete, thanks. On a side note, that last line to get the data in a variable is a comical testimony to the utter rottenness of this language

Comment: note that since windows uses 3 digit PIDs too in those cases it might incorrectly catch the number in the printed memory usage (on some locales only?). PA's answer is better

Comment: @sopel, it should not, there are two spaces as delimiters in the find search string

Comment: @MCND one on each side, yes. So it can catch in here for example `firefox.exe                   9048 Console                    1   296 896 KB`

Answer (score 2):

You can combine **tasklist** and **find** to check if the process with the given pid is running or not.

Then, you can loop around this check to wait for the given pid

```
 :waitforpid
 tasklist /fi "pid eq %1" 2>nul | find "%1" >nul
 if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
   timeout /t 2 /nobreak >nul
   goto :waitforpid
 )
 goto :eof
```

*EDIT:added some sleep*

and use this as

```
 call :waitforpid 1234
```

Comment: this answer is better because it won't get fooled by memory usage

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:check
set stillalive=no
for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('tasklist') do (
set pid=%%a
if !pid! == 1234 (
set stillalive=yes
)
)
if %stillalive% == yes (
cls
 echo/Oh! He's still there, I'll wait.
 goto check
) else (
 echo/He's not there anymore, start the party!!
)
```