# Python avoid orphan processes

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm using python to benchmark something. This can take a large amount of time, and I want to set a (global) timeout. I use the following script (summarized):

```
class TimeoutException(Exception):
    pass
def timeout_handler(signum, frame):
    raise TimeoutException()

# Halt problem after half an hour
signal.alarm(1800)
try:
    while solution is None:
        guess = guess()
        try:
            with open(solutionfname, 'wb') as solutionf:
                solverprocess = subprocess.Popen(["solver", problemfname], stdout=solutionf)
                solverprocess.wait()
        finally:
            # `solverprocess.poll() == None` instead of try didn't work either
            try:
                solverprocess.kill()
            except:
                # Solver process was already dead
                pass
except TimeoutException:
    pass
# Cancel alarm if it's still active
signal.alarm(0)
```

However it keeps spawning orphan processes sometimes, but I can't reliably recreate the circumstances. Does anyone know what the correct way to prevent this is?

Comment: Isn't the first line supposed to be a class?

Comment: @RenaeLider yes, copy error while creating a sample

Comment: related: [Python: how to kill child process(es) when parent dies?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23434842/4279)

Answer (score 2):

You simply have to `wait` after killing the process.

Comment: So if `p.kill()` is called but `p` hasn't exited before python exits `p` isn't killed at all? I'll test if that's true, but why would that be? From what I understand `p.kill()` sends `SIGKILL` to `p` which should cause `p` to die even if python exits.

Comment: @dtech The process *is* killed but *the kernel* does *not* remove it because it is waiting the parent process to read its status.

Comment: @dtech: the process is dead ([SIGKILL always works](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5642/1321)) but the zombie remains until it is reaped. If the original parent process is dead then a dedicated process such as `init 1` will collect the status. Note: [an orphan process must be alive by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process) (its parent is dead). Your code create zombies, not orphans.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for the [`kill()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.kill) method states:

> Kills the child. On Posix OSs the function sends `SIGKILL` to the child.
>   On Windows `kill()` is an alias for `terminate()`.

In other words, if you aren't on Windows, you are *only* sending a signal to the subprocess.
This will create a zombie process because the parent process didn't read the return value of the subprocess.

The `kill()` and `terminate()` methods are just shortcuts to `send_signal(SIGKILL)` and `send_signal(SIGTERM)`.

Try adding a call to `wait()` after the `kill()`. This is even shown in the example under the documentation for [`communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(...)
try:
    outs, errs = proc.communicate(timeout=15)
except TimeoutExpired:
    proc.kill()
    outs, errs = proc.communicate()
```

note the call to `communicate()` after the `kill()`. (It is equivalent to calling `wait()` and also erading the outputs of the subprocess).

---

I want to clarify one thing: it seems like you don't understand exactly what a *zombie process* is. A zombie process is a **terminated** process. The kernel keeps the process in the process table until the parent process reads its exit status. I believe all memory used by the subprocess is actually reused; the kernel only has to keep track of the exit status of such a process.

So, the zombie processes you see aren't running. They are already completely dead, and that's why they are called *zombie*. They are "alive" in the process table, but aren't really running at all.

Calling `wait()` does exactly this: wait till the subprocess ends and read the exit status. This allows the kernel to remove the subprocess from the process table.

Comment: You're right, I meant 'orphan process'. They're definitely not dead because they keep consuming CPU and RAM. I'll try your and Daniel's suggestion.

Comment: @dtech That's a completely different scenario. An orphan process happens when its parent process dies. Then it becomes a child of `init`. In your example I don't really see where these may come from. More information about the subprocess you are launching is required. Also, are you sure that you want to `kill` that subprocess? *That* may cause creation of orphan processes because `kill`ing doesn't allow the subprocess to perform any cleanup. You should first try to call `terminate` and afterwards, if that fails, call `kill`.

Comment: You're right that SIGTERM is probably better, but I don't know how SIGKILL could cause the process to not be killed and be orphaned. The subprocess is a [SAT-solver](http://fmv.jku.at/lingeling/). I'll try it with terminate and calling kill after a while.

Comment: @dtech The sat solver may spawn some subprocess to perform the actual computations. Your `SIGKILL` kills *only* the main process. Using `SIGTERM` *may* let the main process terminate its subprocesses before exiting, it depends on how well it was implemented.

Answer (score 2):

On linux, you can use [python-prctl](https://pythonhosted.org/python-prctl).

Define a preexec function such as:

```
def pre_exec():
    import signal
    prctl.set_pdeathsig(signal.SIGTERM)
```

And have your Popen call pass it.

```
subprocess.Popen(..., preexec_fn=pre_exec)
```

That's as simple as that. Now the child process will die rather than become orphan if the parent dies.

If you don't like the external dependency of python-prctl you can also use the older [prctl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/prctl/1.0.1). Instead of

```
prctl.set_pdeathsig(signal.SIGTERM)
```

you would have

```
prctl.prctl(prctl.PDEATHSIG, signal.SIGTERM)
```