# Spawn a subprocess but kill it if main process gets killed

Tags: python, subprocess

I am creating a program in Python that listens to varios user interactions and logs them. I have these requirements/restrictions:

1. I need a separate process that sends those logs to a remote database every hour
2. I can't do it in the current process because it blocks the UI.
3. If the main process stops, the background process should also stop.

I've been reading about `subprocess` but I can't seem to find anything on how to stop both simultaneously. I need the equivalent of `spawn_link` if anybody know some Erlang/Elixir.

Thanks!

Comment: I know the code would be trivial, but could you show us just a minimal working example about how you spawn your subprocess?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true)

Comment: OS? On windows you can use `win32process.EnumProcesses` to get a list of PID's running on the system.  Your child program could accept the parent PID as a command line argument (or look up its parents' PID itself), then have an `if parentpid not in EnumProcesses(): sys.exit(0)` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the title (for visitors from google): [there are robust solutions on Linux, Windows using OS-specific APIs and less robust but more portable `psutil`-based solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23434842/4279).

---

To fix your specific problem (it is [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/137096)): **use a daemon thread instead of a process**.

A thread would allow to perform I/O without blocking GUI, [code example](https://gist.github.com/zed/42324397516310c86288) (even if GUI you've chosen doesn't provide async. I/O API such as [tkinter's `createfilehandler()`](https://gist.github.com/zed/9294978) or [gtk's `io_add_watch()`](https://gist.github.com/zed/8a255e81eb87431c0e63)).