# How to kill a subprocess started in a thread?

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to run the `Robocopy` command (but I am curious about any subprocess) from Python in windows.  The code is pretty simple and works well.  It is:

```
def copy():
    with Popen(['Robocopy', media_path, destination_path, '/E', '/mir', '/TEE', '/log+:' + log_path], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as Robocopy:
        Robocopy.wait()
        returncode = Robocopy.returncode
```

Additionally I am running it in a separate thread with the following:

```
threading.Thread(target=copy, args=(media_path, destination_path, log_path,), daemon=True)
```

However, there are certain instances where I want to stop the `robocopy` (akin to closing the `CMD` window if it was run from the command line)

Is there a good way to do this in Python?

Comment: unrelated: don't use `stdout=PIPE` unless you read from the pipe. If you don't use `stdout=PIPE` you can drop `bufsize`, `universal_newlines` parameters too.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, 3.3+ also has `subprocess.DEVNULL`, which is a bit simpler than opening `os.devnull`. Using `nul` expands the range of console programs that work with the `DETACHED_PROCESS` flag without requiring pipes. Specifically it helps if a program expects valid standard handles.

Answer (score 1):

We fought with reliably killing subprocesses on Windows for a while and eventually came across this:

```
https://github.com/andreisavu/python-process/blob/master/killableprocess.py
```

It implements a `kill()` method for killing your subprocess.  We've had really good results with it.

You will need to somehow pass the process object out of the thread and call `kill()` from another thread, or poll in your thread with `wait()` using a timeout while monitoring some kind of global-ish flag.

Answer (score 1):

If the process doesn't start other processes then `process.kill()` should work:

```
import subprocess

class InterruptableProcess:
     def __init__(self, *args):
         self._process = subprocess.Popen(args)

     def interrupt(self):
         self._process.kill()
```

I don't see why would you need it on Windows but you could run `Thread(target=self._process.wait, daemon=True).start()` if you'd like.

If there is a possibility that the process may start other processes in turn then you might need a *Job object* to kill all the descendant processes. It seems [`killableprocess.py`](https://github.com/andreisavu/python-process/blob/master/killableprocess.py) which is [suggested by @rrauenza](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37690888/4279) uses this approach (I haven't tested it). See [Python: how to kill child process(es) when parent dies?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23434842/4279).