# How to destroy an .exe file(not converted from py) by run as the same script

Tags: python, subprocess, exe, python-3.4

I have a script that runs an .exe file via `subprocess.Popen()`, but I just realized, that .exe file keeps running even I close my script. Is there any way to stop running an .exe file via name of it or ID? That exe file is not converted from a py file, so I'm stuck.

Comment: Have you tried killing the process? `proc = subprocess.Popen(...)`, wrap the code in a try/finally calling `proc.kill()`

Comment: proc.kill("anexe.exe") like this?

Comment: I mean just call `proc.kill()` , I am not overly familiar with windows but if I say started vlc using a subprocess, if I wanted to kill it I would just call proc.kill() or proc.terminate() depending on how exactly I wanted it to stop

Comment: @GLHF, no, just `proc.kill()`, if `proc` is the name to which you assigned the `Popen` object, exactly as Padraic said.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `process = subprocess.Popen(...)` then you could terminate the process later using `process.terminate()`.

If the subprocess may create its own children then `process.terminate()` and/or `process.kill()` might not be enough. On Windows, you might need to create a *Job object* and assign the `.exe` process to it. On Unix, you could use `start_new_session=True` (`preexec_fn=os.setsid` or `preexec_fn=os.setpgrp` on earlier Python versions) plus `os.pgkill(process.pid, signal.SIGINT)` to kill processes belonging to the same process group (or `prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, ...)` on Linux, to send a signal when the parent dies). See

- [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4789837/4279)
- [Python: how to kill child process(es) when parent dies?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23434842/4279)

See also, [`killableprocess.py`](http://benjamin.smedbergs.us/blog/2006-12-11/killableprocesspy/)