# Python how to terminate a subprocess when the terminal is closed?

Tags: python, subprocess, terminate

I have a script that starts an another script2.py as subprocesses. But when I close the terminal, script2.py still stays runned. How can I terminate a subprocess when closing the terminal(console).

Here is how I start the subprocess:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(command,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                        shell=True)
    command_output = iter(p.stdout.readline, b'')
```

And I normally close it like this: `os.killpg(os.getpgid(p.pid), signal.SIGTERM)`, but how to terminate all subprocesses just by closing the console(terminal)?

Comment: As part of the command to start script2.py, send console/script1.py pid, In script2.py, run a thread to check if pid of script1 exists, as soon pid is lost, exit/close script2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ensuring subprocesses are dead on exiting Python program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320232/ensuring-subprocesses-are-dead-on-exiting-python-program)

Comment: Also possible duplicate of [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true)