# Terminate a Subprocess of Subprocess

Tags: python, terminate

I run 20 subprocesses by using:

```
process1 = subprocess.Popen(command1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
            shell=False, encoding='utf-8', cwd=full_path)
```

`command1` is calling a file named: "scheduleInstasck.py" which triggers also **another command**:

```
process2 = subprocess.Popen(command2, shell=False, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, cwd='./{}'.format(client_folders[running_index]))
```

`command2` is calling a file named: "quickstart.py" which is my app.

Once I call `process1.terminate()` it will only kill process1 while process2  is still alive and I see all logs of it until it finish.

I did try:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/320712/4215840

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31464349/4215840

to catch termination on scheduleInstasck and to do `process2.terminate()` but this never called for some reason on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

For some long-term results I would suggest better indexing and overall process/memory management. An easy solution however, would just to iterate the active child processes of whatever process you are about to kill. `multiprocessing.active_children` is probably what you would want to use. You can also reference [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true/4791612)

Comment: So issues is mostly due to using subprocess ?

Comment: I will implement a web server bit that will hold the status of running, idle, stop_req this is the only way I can find now working, morevover it will be easy to distribute the system later.