# IsProcessInJob with GetCurrentProcess aways true

Tags: jobs, createprocess

(Visual Studio 2010 - C++)
Hello,

I'm trying to set a JOB to a process, but AssignProcessToJobObject returns ACCESS_DENIED and IsProcessInJob returns TRUE.

I call IsProcessInJob to a process immediately after call CreateProcess (Suspended) end tried call IsProcessInJob with my process (a few lines after main entry point) and it returns true.

```
void main()
{   
    BOOL bIsInJob;

    IsProcessInJob( GetCurrentProcess(), NULL, &bIsInJob );
    printf( "IsProcessInJob (me): %s\n", bIsInJob ? "true" : "false" ); 
// RET True ! inside and outside IDE
   ...
```

Someone saw it before?

Thanks for any help.
Sources:
[Kill child process when parent process is killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342941/kill-child-process-when-parent-process-is-killed)
[How do I automatically destroy child processes in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53208/how-do-i-automatically-destroy-child-processes-in-windows)

Comment: Have you checked the return value of IsProcessInJob to see if it is succeeding?  Is this the main process or the subprocess?

Comment: IsProcessInJob (5th line) returns 1.
Main process. (child process is notepad)

Comment: Looks like your process really is in a job, then.  This could be due to software running on your machine, although it is unusual.  Are you able to try running your code on a test machine with no other software installed?

Comment: Also - you could try QueryInformationJobObject, perhaps with JobObjectBasicProcessIdList, to see what you can find out about the mystery job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found.

For some reason, my process was child of Explorer.exe then Explorer set a job to my process and the notepad (my child) inherits this job.

I could not find until see with ProcessExplorer. I can not saw my process in process list, when i find below Winlogon->Explorer, i understood.

Resolution: CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB

```
if (!CreateProcess(L"c:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe",  L"", NULL, NULL, FALSE,
        CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB, NULL, NULL, &startupInfo, &processInformation))
...
```

Thanks for your comments, patience and time.