# How to launch other processes that dies when the parent does?

Tags: c#, winapi

I know I can have the child process monitor the parent.  Is there to have Windows do this automatically?  After all, it does track the process launch hierarchy.

Comment: You cannot rely on jobs when your program gets started from a shortcut on the desktop.  In Vista, the shell already uses jobs for appcompat.  Big frown upside down when I discovered that.  Not sure if it is still this way in Win7.  A third guard process is the generic solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Jobs, try the [`SetInformationJobObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, the key is use the `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE` value in the `LimitFlags` member of the [_JOBOBJECT_BASIC_LIMIT_INFORMATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684147%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) struct passed to the function.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this nativly through C#.  You will need to use PInvoke to call the Win32 [Job API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The API calls are in this answer:
[How do I automatically destroy child processes in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53208/how-do-i-automatically-destroy-child-processes-in-windows)