# Set Parent of New Process

Tags: c++, windows, dll, parent-child, process

I'm trying to associate a child process with a dll that's being loaded by an external application. The reason being that I want this child process to close as soon as the dll is unloaded.

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53208/how-do-i-automatically-destroy-child-processes-in-windows) for guidance, but, by default, it appears that `CreateProcess` is associating the child process with the external application instead of the DLL that is calling it.

Here is a snippet of code that might explain what I'm trying to achieve:

From the DLL:

```
// ... Initialize ghJob to JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE

if (::CreateProcess( NULL, szCmdline , NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB , NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo)) // <-- Here is where I'd like to set the parent to the calling DLL
{
    // SetParent(processInfo.hProcess, dllHinst) <-- This isn't right, but something like this
    AssignProcessToJobObject( ghJob, processInfo.hProcess);
}
```

Any insight on this issue would be much appreciated, especially if I'm going about this the wrong way.

Comment: Basically, a DLL is just a chunk of code shared among processes. I don't think it's possible to have the system bind a given process to the lifespan of a DLL: it is the opposit that is happening, a DLL is loaded once in memory, and bound to the processes which require it, and may be unloaded once no processes using it are running anymore.

Comment: Why do you need to bind a process to a dll?

Comment: Use [LdrRegisterDllNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347461.aspx) to receive a notification when that DLL unloads.

Comment: @didierc Hmm, the DLL is registered as a COM object so it's possible that it'll be loaded/unloaded a few times. The reason why I wanted to bind it to a DLL was to make sure that the attached process would close even if the DLL was torn down ungracefully.

Comment: Now that I think about it, though, if the DLL/COM object is removed ungracefully, it's likely the hosting application itself has crashed, so attaching a process to the host application will work in preventing the attached process from hanging around after the DLL is gone away by means of a crash.

Since I also have access to when the DLL is closing gracefully, I can just call TerminateProcess on the handle of the attached process.

Comment: If you close the handle to the job object in your DLL close function, this will have the same effect on the child processes as if the process had exited.  TerminateProcess will work on the child process too, but not on any grandchildren (or at least not easily).