# Windows API Job Objects: Don't pass on to grandchildren

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, createprocess

I have a Windows command line application `child.exe` for which I wish to create a wrapper, `parent.exe`. I do this by spawning the child from the parent using `CreateProcess`:

```
int wmain(int argc, WCHAR *argv[]) {
    STARTUPINFO startupInfo = createStartupInfo();
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo = {0};
    if(CreateProcessW(
        L"C:\\child.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE,
        CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &startupInfo, &processInfo
    )) {
        WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
        CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
        return 0;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

STARTUPINFO createStartupInfo() {
    // Create and return a STARTUPINFO structure...
}
```

I now want the child process to be terminated when the parent process closes. Following [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53208/how-do-i-automatically-destroy-child-processes-in-windows), I am using *Job Objects* to do so:

```
// Create and initialise the job object:
HANDLE ghJob = CreateJobObject(NULL, NULL);
if (ghJob == NULL) { /* Error handling... */ }
else {
    JOBOBJECT_EXTENDED_LIMIT_INFORMATION jeli = { 0 };
    // Configure all child processes associated with the
    // job to terminate when the parent closes:
    jeli.BasicLimitInformation.LimitFlags = 
        JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE;
    if (! SetInformationJobObject(
        ghJob, JobObjectExtendedLimitInformation, &jeli, sizeof(jeli)
    )) { /* Error handling... */ }
}
```

I then assign the created child process to this job via `AssignProcessToJobObject`:

```
if(CreateProcessW(...)) {
    AssignProcessToJobObject(ghJob, processInfo.hProcess));
    WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    ...
} ...
```

This works: Because the newly created process is assigned to a job with `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE`, the child process is automatically terminated when the parent process closes for whatever reason.

**But here is my problem**: I don't have control over `child.exe`. It spawns its own sub-processes (say `grandchild.exe`), so we have:

```
parent.exe -> child.exe -> grandchild.exe
```

Unfortunately, this "spawning of `grandchild.exe`" fails when I assign the job object to `child.exe` as above. I believe this is because `grandchild.exe` inherits my job definition but `child.exe` tries to apply its own job definition to `grandchild.exe` and fails because on Windows 7 a job may only be associated with a single job. The [docs for `AssignProcessToJobObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681949(v=vs.85).aspx) say that if one wishes to create processes that do not inherit the job from their parent, one has to use the `CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB` flag when calling `CreateProcess`. But the problem is that this call to `CreateProcess` happens inside `child.exe`, to which I have no access.

Can anybody think of a solution that allows `child.exe` to freely spawn its own (grand)child processes, while at the same time making it possible for me to terminate `child.exe` when `parent.exe` is closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to to set the `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_SILENT_BREAKAWAY_OK` flag on the job.  This flag prevents child processes from being automatically assigned to the job.

Use the [`SetInformationJobObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686216(v=vs.85).aspx) function and the `JobObjectExtendedLimitInformation` option.  The flag is set in the `MyExtendedLimitInformation.BasicLimitInformation.LimitFlags` member.