# Chromium Embedded Framework - Kill parent process if a sub-process is terminated

Tags: chromium, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I have been looking around the chromium embedded framework docs and cannot find any obvious solution.

What is the recommended way for the parent process (CEFProject.exe) to terminate if a sub-process is terminated (CefSharp.BrowserSubProcess.exe).

I have found an approach to do terminate the child processes when the parent process is shut-down [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53208/how-do-i-automatically-destroy-child-processes-in-windows), but not the other way round.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: If you look at the `CEF API` you will see there is a method called ` CefRequestHandler::OnRenderProcessTerminated` http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefRequestHandler.html#OnRenderProcessTerminated(CefRefPtr%3CCefBrowser%3E,TerminationStatus) which maps to `IRequestHandler.OnRenderProcessTerminated`, search the source if you need an example.

Comment: I don't believe there us a notification for when the `GPU` process is terminated, you can of course disable the `GPU` and their won't be a `GPU` process.